# Selenium Webdriver: How to find element by locators

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm using Selenium Webdriver and would like to find this element:

Below is HTML code-

```
<span ng-class="{'details-section': isSingle(b) && !isExist(b)}">1.00</span>
```

Tried this one below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@ng-class='{'details-section': isSingle(b) && !isExist(b)}']")).getText();
```

Unfortunatelly the following error I'm receiving:

> **unknown error: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined**

Can you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `'` inside the XPATH

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@ng-class='{\'details-section\': isSingle(b) && !isExist(b)}']")).getText();
```

Also it is not a very good idea to to a full compare, so if possible do a partial one. Because even a small space change will break the code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@ng-class,'isSingle(b)')][contains(@ng-class,'!isExist(b)')]
```